# Did Joseph Stalin ever attempt to assassinate or launch a coup against Josip Broz Tito?

Tags: soviet-union, cold-war, yugoslavia

Did Joseph Stalin ever attempt to assassinate or launch a coup against Josip Broz Tito? If so, which of these coup or assassination attempts almost succeeded? How did Tito respond to Stalin's pressures?

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct evidence that any Stalin-backed plot to kill Tito was ever really put into action. Tito [claimed](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2175385/Did-Tito-poison-Stalin-Historian-claims-Yugoslav-dictator-killed-rival-target-22-Soviet-assassination-attempts.html) that several attempts were made to kill him and that Stalin was behind them, and Stalin did actually want for Tito to be assassinated. Several potential methods were discussed, but [none were carried out](http://articles.latimes.com/1993-06-12/news/mn-2405_1_yugoslav-leader).